# Spring Boot Starter : Retry Transaction Question

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm using the mybatis-spring-boot-starter (2.0.1) and I'm having an issue where sometimes I get a deadlock writing to mysql:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:123)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:637)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:418)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:370)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:47)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
```

This is transient and I think it happens with load and I also think it is normal and can be solved with a simple retry.

However, I'm not sure where/how to implement the retry. I know spring supports AOP and also the @retry annotation, etc. but since the s-b-s makes things so easy, I only declare a datasource in my config and a bunch of @Mapper interfaces and s-b-s takes care of everything else.

I'm curious if the s-b-s has a simple way to add/enable retry on failed deadlock exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Spring Retry. Spring Retry provides an ability to automatically re-invoke a failed operation. Please note this is helpful where the errors may be transient in nature (like a momentary network glitch). Spring Retry provides declarative control of the process and policy-based behavior that is easy to extend and customize.

Check out the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) and [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html)

Comment: Thank you. As you can see in my original message, I have considered that but I don't have any idea where to "bolt it on" and add the Spring Retry annotation since I don't have the code available (it's all in the Spring Boot MyBatis plugin and autoconfigured)